# How to render picture from json file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My output request is the picture list . i get the path src from json file and then i set it  for img tag when loop  but it cannot be loaded. Please help to find out my mistake . Many thanks !

```
//Here is a json file

[
  {
    "name": "Dublin",
    "subText": "123 properties",
    "image": "../../assets/images/hotel_2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Reno",
    "subText": "533 properties",
    "image": "../assets/images/city_2.webp"
  },
  {
    "name": "Austin",
    "subText": "532 properties",
    "image": "../assets/images/city_3.webp"
  }
]

//here is my conponent
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

CityListItem.propTypes = {
  cityList: PropTypes.array,
};

CityListItem.defaultProps = {
  cityList: [],
};

function CityListItem(props) {
  const {cityList} = props;
  return (
    <>
      {cityList.map((city) => (
        <div key={city.name} className='cityList__item'>
          <img src={city.image} alt={city.name} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
export default CityListItem;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have specified the correct path for your image. From what I can see your array object at `0 index` is setting a different path. Also, make sure you have images with the same extension stored in the way that you have specified.

Here is a working example, you can refer to this [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/embed/image-exampe-json-lfux8w?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: yes, i just wanna test this path so that i changed it